# Is there any way to create a stand-alone ButtonSpec in Krypton Toolkit?

Tags: .net, user-interface, krypton-toolkit

I need to create a button that has the same style as `ButtonSpec` with its type set to `Context`, is there any way to create a `ButtonSpec` that isn't directly attached to another control, or have I missed a simple style option on another control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a standalone ButtonSpec but you do not need one. Create a KryptonButton and then set the ButtonStyle to be ButtonSpec and it will draw in the same way as a ButtonSpec that is present in other controls. You could use a KryptonDropButton if you need it to show a KryptonContextMenu when pressed.

Comment: Is there any way to set the button's image to the same image that setting the ButtonSpec.Type might?  I already tried setting the ButtonStyle, and it just seems to remove the border from the button.

Comment: No, you cannot get the image from ButtonSpec.Type. There might be another approach. Try creating a KryptonHeader with a ButtonSpec and then remove all the content of the KryptonHeader.Values. Then remove the drawing of the header background/border and you end up with only a buttonspec!